# How to change magento My Account links order

Tags: magento-1.8

Hi I need to change magento my account links order. Now it looks like bellow

- Account Information
- Address Book
- My Orders
- My Wishlist

I need to change the order like,

- My Orders
- My Wishlist
- Account Information
- Address Book

Answer (score 6):

Magento core code  not provide this type of works.So we need a create 
extension

**1)** In `app/etc/modules/Bh_Customerlink.xml`  and code of this file

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Bh_Customerlink>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
            </Bh_Customerlink>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

2)Create a block in `app/code/local/Bh/Customerlink/Block/Customer/Account/Navigation.php` & put the following code

```
 <?php
class Bh_Customerlink_Block_Customer_Account_Navigation extends Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation
        {
            public function removeLinkByName($name) {
                unset($this->_links[$name]);
            }
        }
```

**3)**Create module configuration file at `app/code/local/Bh/Customerlink/etc/config.xml` and code of this file in below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <BH_Customerlink>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </BH_Customerlink>
        </modules>
        <frontend>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                    <bH_customerlink>
                        <file>customerlink.xml</file>
                    </bH_customerlink>
                </updates>
            </layout>
        </frontend>

        <global>
            <blocks>
            <customer>
                <rewrite>
                    <account_navigation>BH_Customerlink_Block_Customer_Account_Navigation</account_navigation>
                </rewrite>
            </customer>
        </blocks>
        </global>
      </config>
```

**4)**Replace code in a`pp/design/frontend/default/default/layout/customerlink.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">
        <customer_account translate="label">
            <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
                <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>account</name></action>
                <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>account_edit</name></action>            
                <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>address_book</name></action>
                <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>reviews</name></action>
                <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>orders</name></action>
                <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>newsletter</name></action>
                <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>billing_agreements</name></action>
                <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>recurring_profiles</name></action>
                <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>tags</name></action>
                <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>wishlist</name></action>
                <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>OAuth Customer Tokens</name></action>
                <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>downloadable_products</name></action>
            </reference>
        </customer_account>
        <customer_account translate="label">
            <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
                <action method="addLink"><name>orders</name><path>sales/order/history/</path><label>My Order</label></action>
                <action method="addLink"><name>wishlist</name><path>wishlist/</path><label>My Wishlist</label></action>
                <action method="addLink"><name>account_edit</name><path>customer/account/edit/</path><label>Account Information</label></action>
                <action method="addLink"><name>address_book</name><path>customer/address/</path><label>Address Book</label></action>        
                <action method="addLink"><name>billing_agreements</name><path>sales/billing_agreement/</path><label>Billing Agreements</label></action>
                <action method="addLink"><name>recurring_profiles</name><path>sales/recurring_profile/</path><label>Recurring Profiles</label></action>
                <action method="addLink"><name>reviews</name><path>review/customer/</path><label>My Product Reviews</label></action>
                <action method="addLink"><name>tags</name><path>tag/customer/</path><label>My Tags</label></action>
                <action method="addLink"><name>address_book</name><path>oauth/customer_token/</path><label>My Applications</label></action>
                <action method="addLink"><name>OAuth Customer Tokens</name><path>newsletter/manage/</path><label>Newsletter Subscriptions</label></action>
                <action method="addLink"><name>downloadable_products</name><path>downloadable/customer/products/</path><label>My Downloadable Products</label></action>


            </reference>
        </customer_account>

    </layout>
```

Now you can add/remove or re-arrange customer links.    I hope it will be help you.

Comment: Thanks for the effort :-).I am not have any file named Bh_Customerlinl.xml. But I can create  a custom module with same name. Before going to create  a custom module can you please explain me how this changes will work. Because the code not seems ok for my question... Is it reorder my account links?

Comment: The above code, You can remove/add  any link from customer account left navigation. Other words, You can re-arrange the default customer account left navigation links.

Comment: Thanks, your updated answer help me to do the changes. I have removed <reference name="customer_account_navigation"> from the sales.xml and added <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>orders</name><path>sales/order/history/</path><label>Orders</label></action> into the customer.xml. same for wishlist. So now I got what I want. Thanks for your help. Please remove your custom code,and keep it ur updated code. I will accept it as a answer.

Comment: Update my layout xml. plesse see.

Answer (score 2):

By default Magento `addLink()` function for customer account section (which is under: `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Navigation.php`) only takes 4 parameters, i.e.

- name
- path
- label
- urlParams = array()

It does not take position of links. If you want to set position from layout xml files, then you need to first override `Navigation.php` block file and change method `addLink()` to have parameter for position also. Then you can set position parameter position in layout xml files.

I hope you will get my point from above solution. If you have any question, then please feel free to post here.

Answer (score 1):

```
<reference name="left">
            <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" after="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>Account Dashboard</label></action>
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account_edit</name><path>customer/account/edit/</path><label>Account Information</label></action>
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>address_book</name><path>customer/address/</path><label>Address Book</label></action>
            </block>
</reference>
```

In customer links and remove extra tab and use before with order and wishlist links from xml

Answer (score 1):

you do not need to create a new module.just add this code to your local.xml

```
<customer_account>
    <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>orders</name><path>sales/order/history/</path><label>My Orders</label></action> 
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="wishlist" ifconfig="wishlist/general/active"><name>wishlist</name><path>wishlist/</path><label>My Wishlist</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account_edit</name><path>customer/account/edit/</path><label>Account Informations</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>address_book</name><path>customer/address/</path><label>Address Book</label></action>
    </block>
</customer_account>
```

here example image [image: here example image]

tested on Magento ver. 1.9.0.1

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this without a module, and without any XML, hooray! Someone might say this is a bit non-Magento "hacky", but it's pure PHP.

The customer account navigation is *assembled* in a file located at **app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/account/navigation.phtml**; If you intend to use this method, **do not** modify the original file, instead copy that file to your own theme and modify it there.

File: **app/design/frontend/theme/path/template/customer/account/navigation.phtml**:

```
<div class="block block-account">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('My Account'); ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <ul id="account-nav">
            <?php $_links = $this->getLinks(); ?>
            <?php $_index = 1; ?>
            <?php $_count = count($_links); ?>
            <?php 
                if ( $_count ) {
                    // unset($_links['account']); /* Account Info */
                    // unset($_links['account_edit']); /* Account Info */
                    unset($_links['tags']); /* My Tags */
                    unset($_links['invitations']); /* My Invitations */
                    unset($_links['reviews']);  /* Reviews */
                    unset($_links['wishlist']); /* Wishlist */
                    // unset($_links['newsletter']); /* Newsletter */
                    // unset($_links['orders']); /* My Orders */
                    // unset($_links['address_book']); /* Address */
                    unset($_links['enterprise_customerbalance']); /* Store Credit */
                    unset($_links['OAuth Customer Tokens']); /* My Applications */
                    unset($_links['enterprise_reward']); /* Reward Points */
                    unset($_links['giftregistry']); /* Gift Registry */
                    unset($_links['downloadable_products']); /* My Downloadable Products */
                    unset($_links['recurring_profiles']); /* Recurring Profiles */
                    unset($_links['billing_agreements']); /* Billing Agreements */
                    unset($_links['enterprise_giftcardaccount']); /* Gift Card Link */
                }

                $_linkOrder = array('account', 'account_edit', 'orders', 'address_book', 'newsletter');
                $_orderedLinks = array();

                foreach ( $_linkOrder as $index ) {
                    $_orderedLinks[$index] = $_links[$index];
                }
            ?>

            <?php foreach ($_orderedLinks as $_link): ?>
                <?php $_last = ($_index++ >= $_count); ?>
                <?php if ($this->isActive($_link)): ?>
                    <li class="current<?php echo ($_last ? ' last' : '') ?>"><strong><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></strong></li>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <li<?php echo ($_last ? ' class="last"' : '') ?>><a href="<?php echo $_link->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></a></li>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**What's happening here:**

First we unset (delete from the **$_links** array) those items we don't want. I've put all the default options in for convenience, just comment out the links you want to **keep**.

Next we create a new array to sort by, sort the **$_links** array against that one, and we are done.

I personally prefer this method because:

- This encompasses links order, and item customisation.
- It is all in one place.
- No XML!
- Uses pure PHP.
- I'm convinced it renders faster than the XML route.

I hope that works for some folks.