# Magento 2 - How to rearrange Customer "My Account" links

Tags: magento2, module, customer, layered-navigation, customer-account

Now it looks like this:

- Account Dashboard
- Account Information
- Address Book
- My Downloadable Products
- My Orders
- Newsletter Subscription
- Billing Agreements
- My Product Reviews
- My Wish List

I want to change the order to something like this:

- Account Dashboard
- My Orders
- My Downloadable Products
- My Wish List
- My Product Reviews
- Newsletter Subscription
- Account Information
- Address Book
- Billing Agreements

I would prefer to edit the existing module and not to make new one

There is a similar question on stackexchange but it is for Magento 1
[How to change magento My Account links order](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25700/how-to-change-magento-my-account-links-order)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

We can rearrange these links by using "move". Reference to [Magento document](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html) for more detail.
Assume that you are working on customer_account.xml on your theme. In my case:

File path:
                     app/design/frontend/Lhc/diamond/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <move element="customer-account-navigation-orders-link" destination="customer_account_navigation" before="customer-account-navigation-account-edit-link"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

The same with remain links you would like to sort. "customer-account-navigation-orders-link" is the block name in layout, using "before" and "after" element.

Comment: This does not work for me. I am able to move the block to a new destination (catalog.topnav for example. However, If I try to reorder with-in the customer_account_navigation block it does not work

Comment: using <move> also has no effect for me :/  Also tried sortOrder..

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post but you can change the order by changing the number here in the `XML's`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-orders-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">sales/order/history</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order History</argument>
                <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">220</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

So if you want sales order history to be next to My dashboard you'd need to change `220` to `240`. Its `240` because the dashboard order number is `250`.

Comment: Worked very well. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For rearrange or change account link label override  customer_account.xml into your theme or existing custom module.

in theme ...

```
app/design/frontend/{{vendor}}/{{theme}}/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml
```

or in existing custom module.

```
app/code/{{vendor}}/{{modulename}}/view/frontend/layout/
```

and update order of your link where you want to move.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">
    <head>
        <title>My Account</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- 
            <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-downloadable-products-link" remove="true"/>       
            <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-billing-agreements-link" remove="true"/>
        -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-account-link">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Account Dashboard</argument>
                            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account</argument>
                            <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">250</argument>
                        </arguments>
            </block> 
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-orders-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">sales/order/history</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Orders</argument>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">249</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-downloadable-products-link">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">downloadable/customer/products</argument>
                            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Downloadable Products</argument>
                            <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">248</argument>
                        </arguments>
            </block> 
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" ifconfig="wishlist/general/active" name="customer-account-navigation-wish-list-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">wishlist</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Wish List</argument>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">247</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>

            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-product-reviews-link" ifconfig="catalog/review/active">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">review/customer</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Product Reviews</argument>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">246</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>

            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" ifconfig="newsletter/general/active" name="customer-account-navigation-newsletter-subscriptions-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">newsletter/manage</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Newsletter Subscriptions</argument>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">245</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>

            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-account-edit-link">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Account Information</argument>
                            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account/edit</argument>
                            <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">244</argument>
                        </arguments>
            </block>   

            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-address-link">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Address Book</argument>
                            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/address</argument>
                            <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">243</argument>
                        </arguments>
            </block>


            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-billing-agreements-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">paypal/billing_agreement</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Billing Agreements</argument>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">242</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>



            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-my-credit-cards-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">vault/cards/listaction</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Payment Data</argument>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">241</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>

        </referenceBlock>
    </body> </page>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add property `after` with block name in block to rearrange my account links. 
eg: here i have place after 'wishlist' `after="customer-account-navigation-wish-list-link"`:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-newsletter-subscriptions-link" after="customer-account-navigation-wish-list-link"></block>
```

Comment: You should specify which file to add this to, keeping in mind the requirement not to add a new module.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone comes across this old question and wants to do this without coding...
We published an extension for Magento 2 that allows to disable/remove, but also sort Customer Account Links by Configuration from Backend:
For more details please see [Customer Account Links Manager Extension](https://www.jajuma.de/en/jajuma-develop/extensions/customer-navigation-manager-extension-for-magento-2)

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking to reorder the customer account custom navigation link .This is the code that would go either

app/design/frontend/{{vendor}}/{{theme}}/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml

OR

app/code/{{vendor}}/{{modulename}}/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-custom">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">buyback/customer/index</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Trade Orders</argument>
                 <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">230</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```