# How to re-order My Account navigation links

Tags: magento2, layout, navigation, reorder

My question might be possibly duplicate of [Magento 2 - How to rearrange Customer "My Account" links](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105997/magento-2-how-to-rearrange-customer-my-account-links?atw=1) 
but I really have no idea why my code is not working as expected

My current links order is:

- My Account
- My Orders
- My Downloadable Products
- My Wish List
- ...
- ...
- Newsletter Subscriptions
- My Current Designs
- Preview Order Artwork
- My Saved Quotes
- My Credit Cards (eWAY)

I want it like :

- My Account
- My Orders
- My Current Designs
- Preview Order Artwork
- My Saved Quotes
- My Wish List
- ...
- ...
- Newsletter Subscriptions
- My Credit Cards (eWAY)

This is my code

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/module/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
     <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-downloadable-products-link" remove="true" />
     <move element="customer-account-navigation-my-designs" destination="customer_account_navigation" after="customer-account-navigation-orders-link" />
     <move element="customer-account-navigation-mycard" destination="customer_account_navigation" after="customer-account-navigation-my-designs" />
     <move element="customer-account-navigation-my-saved-cards" destination="customer_account_navigation" after="customer-account-navigation-mycard" />
   </body>
</page>
```

but my output is this.
[image]

Comment: Welcome Nikky to join Magento SE. Did you try with sortOrder? For example: `vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml`

Comment: Thanks for welcoming me here. Yeah I tried sortOrder too but that Dosen't seems to be working!